# Save data / objects without python / pandas / pickle dependencies?

Tags: python, pandas, database, pickle

I am trying to save / load data and objects in Python. I usually use pickle to save pandas data frame and custom objects. Recently I had to change python version (from 3.6 to 3.8) and pandas / pickle version accordingly. I now have trouble to read previous pickled version. I have found some ways to deal with that (ranging from using some pickle options to reloading / rewriting the data).

However I would be interested in a more generic way to save data / objects that would be python / packages independant. Does such a thing exists (without adding to much weird dependencies) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you save your data as a .CSV file (depending on what your data looks like) you should'nt get dependencies problem

If your data cannot be saved as a csv I think using JSON could also be a solution